# Delete rows from a large table with joins and aggregating (resulting in 1 % less rows in the big table)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I got a bit stuck on performance, so I thought about asking a bit of help. I have a working query, but unfortunatelly it feels rather slow and I know it's not as performant as it could be made (easily?). The situation is to delete rows from a table which contain around one million rows, by doing a join to another table likewise having around a million rows worth of data (these tables have about the same amount of rows). The result after removing rows from `SomeList` is that there's about 1 % less rows

The table structure is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE SomeList
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TimeData DateTime NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SomeListAuxData
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CountData INT NOT NULL,
    SomeListId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SomeList(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And the query to delete as follows

```
DELETE
FROM SomeList 
WHERE TimeData < @someTime AND Id = @someListId AND
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM SomeListAuxData
    WHERE SomeList.Id = SomeListAuxData.SomeListId
) > 0
AND
(
    SELECT MAX(CountData)
    FROM SomeListAuxData
    WHERE SomeList.Id = SomeListAuxData.SomeListId
) < @someValue;
```

Specifically this seem wasteful since I'm doing two subqueries, but I'm not sure how to go about the `COUNT(*)` and `MAX(CountData)` parts if I'd try joining, for instance.

This query is made in a program code where the someListIds are looped with same the `@someValue` (e.g. `2000`) and @someTime (e.g. `'2013-11-07 09:00:00.000'`) dates, so that too is rather slow. The query could be done for all the `SomeList` rows at once.

**<edit:** Also, I just learned that the code calling does have a list of pairs of type (`@someListId`, `@someDate`), which means the date isn't a constant. The input comes from the user interfaces and typically there may be even hundreds of such pairs.

Also, maybe scheduling a job at night may do the job. Though I'll need to checks Craig's advice which seem to be valid too. :)

**<edit:** I clarified what I meant by the "1 %" in my question. The point to make was that I don't think the data warrants collecting the non-removable rows to a `#temptable`, truncating `SomeList` and then moving the data from `#temptable"` back to `SomeList`. Craig's good point answered (partially) a different question, nevertheless it may be applicable. Sorry for my sloppy writing.

<edit 2013-11-08: The join conditions corrected as suggeted in comments.

Comment: You can rewrite the `COUNT(*)` subquery as an `EXISTS` subquery. But even better, you can remove it! If the `MAX(CountData)` subquery returns a value and it is `> @someValue`, then surely the (COUNT or EXISTS) subquery will yield TRUE as result.

Comment: And seems you have a typo in the code. It should be `WHERE SomeList.Id = SomeListAuxData.SomeListId`, correct?

Comment: Indeed, I had a typo there (will be fixed). About your other note, that probably was what kept bugging me, but I was slow to notice it (before reading this, that is)! I kept thinking that these two subselects are so redundant, why two, why not one and just join the MAX (and do I need DENSE_RANK, huh?) etc. Now it's much clearer. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an inline function which does return only these rows which are to be deleted:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [uf_deletable_SomeLists]
(
    @someTime DATETIME,
    @someValue INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT sl.[Id]
    FROM [SomeList] AS sl
    INNER JOIN [SomeListAuxData] AS sla
        ON sl.[Id] = sla.[SomeListId]
        AND sl.[TimeData] < @someTime
    GROUP BY sl.[Id]
    HAVING MAX(sla.[CountData]) < @someValue
)
```

If you would call the function on the following table set up

```
SELECT * FROM [SomeList]

Id          TimeData
----------- -----------------------
2           2013-11-06 16:55:50.280
3           2013-11-06 16:55:56.667
4           2013-11-06 16:56:24.217

SELECT * FROM [SomeListAuxData]

Id          CountData   SomeListId
----------- ----------- -----------
2           1           2
4           5           2
3           5           4
5           10          4
```

the result would look like this

```
SELECT * FROM [uf_deletable_SomeLists]('20140101', 10)

Id
-----------
2
```

Now you can combine the inline function with a delete statement using a join

```
DELETE [SomeList]
FROM [SomeList] AS sl
INNER JOIN [uf_deletable_SomeLists](@someTime, @someValue) AS d
    ON sl.[Id] = d.[Id]
    AND sl.[Id] = @someListId
```

If you want you can remove the @someListId, that will use the whole SomeList table.
Or you add a second join with a temporary table containing SomeList Id's which you may want to delete.

You can include the percentage statement mentioned by [Craig Efrein](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/delete-rows-from-a-large-table-with-joins-and-aggregating-resulting-in-1-less/52943#52943) as well...

```
DELETE TOP(1) PERCENT [SomeList]
FROM [SomeList] AS sl (...)
```

To boost the select you could consider using an index.
For my machine the execution plan was a bit better if I used the following index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_SomeListAuxData_SomeListId] ON [SomeListAuxData]
    ( [SomeListId] ASC )
INCLUDE ( [CountData] )
```

---

**UPDATE:**
You can always take the query from the function and use it directly as a nested one for the delete statement. But creating the function gives you the option to reuse the query for example to check beforehand which would be deleted if you would call the delete. Incidentally the inline function is basically just a server-side stored parameterised query (I would have used a view if @someTime and @someValue would have been constants). The benefits of inline functions have been discussed in other posts or pages, i.e. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2554544).

Comment: Hmm, the first time I see functions actually used. I'll check this and get back to you. Creating a temporary table and joining it feels a tempting route to take (with or without the function).

Comment: @Veksi I have updated my answer to explain why I used an inline function.

Comment: I did see, thank you very much. As an explanation an apology for my prolonged absence (what can I say), we had a Father's Day (we had it last weekend rather than, say, summer) and quite energy draining cold. Anyhow, this was most useful, I'd say!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already referencing the SomeList table from the SomeListAuxData table, why not add "ON DELETE CASCADE" to the foreign constraint definition on SomeListAuxData?

```
CREATE TABLE SomeListAuxData
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CountData INT NOT NULL,
    SomeListId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SomeList(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This way, if you delete record with an id of 1 in the SomeList table, any record in SomeListAuxData referencing record 1 will be deleted as well.

As to deleting a % of rows at a time, I like to use a loop. This one deletes 10,000 records at a time, until there are none left.

```
delete top (10000) from SomeList WHERE TimeData < @someTime AND Id = @someListId
  WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN
        waitfor delay '00:00:05' -- add in a delay optional

        delete top (10000) from SomeList WHERE TimeData < @someTime AND Id = @someListId

  END
```

**Update 14:09**

Using the [TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) operator, you can also specify a percent of rows.

```
DELETE TOP(1) PERCENT
FROM SomeList 
WHERE TimeData < @someTime AND Id = @someListId AND
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM SomeListAuxData
    WHERE SomeListAuxData.Id = SomeListAuxData.SomeListId
) > 0
AND
(
    SELECT MAX(CountData)
    FROM SomeListAuxData
    WHERE SomeListAuxData.Id = SomeListAuxData.SomeListId
) < @someValue;
```

Comment: A good point, I just had missed it when stripping the original tables (to protect the innocent and lessen the burden, and I undertand by doing so index data and such isn't there either, but I believe the query in itself is the problem).

Comment: I also clarified my question regarding the "1 %" part. You have a good point, though (albeit I don't have the reputation to vote you up).

Comment: Hello @Veksi, for such large deletes, its best to let SQL Server do the heavy lifting. Even if you were using Express, you could schedule the job directly in Task Scheduler for Windows. Either way, deleting millions of rows using code in your application is not optimal.

Comment: Indeed, it has become a somewhat acute problem. I'm a programmer (as you can probably tell), but I try not to be too unprecise or glance over important details here. I mean SQL Server Job, but I feel that too isn't a good fit if I can just avoid that. For what I can see, time is spent in querying and then deleting. The first impression I had, have, is that the query could be better (I even searched on pivot over stuff etc.) and that could be enough. Unfortunately this query is run 1-2 times an hour and I can't do anything about it (currently, at least).

Comment: @Veksi - Updated my answer